# count row with total

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

From tbl Department, I am trying to write a stored procedure to display output as shown below where I can find the count from each row based on following conditions:

1. Total = 100
2. Total >100 and <=200
3. Total >200 and <=300
4. Total >300 
   [image]

   set @select = 'select count(*) as Orders, sum (tbl.Expenses) as Total from tbl group by tbl.Department'

So, how can I dynamically get the output for 4 conditions as shown above based on my @select statement.

Comment: battery almost flat - look at GROUP BY and HAVING

Comment: hello mike, I am trying to display the output as shown above by calling stored procedure. It is not a table.

Comment: The query itself is really simple. What is nearly impossible is trying to figure out what you want because you didn't give us any details. That is what @MikeK is trying to say.

Comment: Take a look at this article for the approach to asking t-sql questions. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want conditional aggregation:

```
select sum(case when total = 100 then 1 else 0 end) as condition1,
       sum(case when total > 100 and total <= 200 then 1 else 0 end) as condition2,
       sum(case when total > 200 and total <= 300 then 1 else 0 end) as condition3,
       sum(case when total > 300 then 1 else 0 end) as condition4
from department d;
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope that it would be helpful to you,
Select total,
 Sum (Case when total = 100 then NumberOfOrders_Created end ) As "Condition1",
 Sum (Case when total > 100 and total <= 200 then NumberOfOrders_Created end ) As "Condition2",
 Sum (Case when total > 200 and total <= 300 then NumberOfOrders_Created end ) As "Condition3",
 Sum (Case when total > 200 and total <= 300 then NumberOfOrders_Created end ) As "Condition4",
From Department
where 
Orders_date between '2013-01-01 00:00:00' and '2013-12-31 00:00:00'
group by 2
order by 1 Desc